# find clock cycle time for pipelined and unpipelined caches?

Tags: pipeline

Consider a 2-way set associative cache with the timing of its different units that is 
given in Table 2. Consider two possible designs for this cache: unpipelined and pipelined. (30 
points) 
a) What would be the cycle time for both caches? What is the maximum frequency at 
which the processor can run in both cases? 
b) Given that all memory references for some program hit in the cache, then compare the 
performance of the two caches in terms of cache access latency and throughput. Assume 
that tag comparisons are performed using two separate comparators in both cases and 
each of the units in the pipelined cache is used in one cycle only. 
c) Assuming that the miss rate for both caches to be 5% and the miss penalty is 10 ns for 
unpipelined cache and 7 ns for the pipelined cache. Compare the performance of the two 
caches in terms of AMAT. 
Table 2. Cache Attributes 
Unit Delay (ns) 
Cache Indexing 0.4 
Reading Tags and Data 0.4 
Writing Data into Cache 0.3 
Comparator 0.2 
Block Multiplexor 0.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a homework question and you should, at least, show you have tried to answer it yourself first.

Comment: actually i tried to solve it but i need some help

Comment: the clock cycle for unpipelined = 1.5 ns 
(.4+.4+.2+.3+.2)
the max freq 1/1.5=.66 HZ